# Django Rest Framework: An example how to post a new ordering of tracks

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and I have a situation similar to the Album and Tracks example used in the documentation here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#api-reference

I want to make an endpoint that allows me to post this JSON data

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12},{"id":13},{"id":75},{"id":76},{"id":77},{"id":78}]
```

so that the Tracks will be reordered accordingly within the Album they belong to.

The ids in the JSON data refer to the primary key of the tracks within **a specific album**.

The field I use to store their order is `order` and the unique index is `unique_together = ('album', 'order')`

I can write my own custom endpoint to satisfy this, but was wondering if I can reuse whatever existing code that DRF already has to fulfill this.

I have looked at https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk but I am using Django Rest 3.6.3 Django 1.10, python 3 so it appears to be outdated for me.

I want to update the new ordering of the tracks within **one specific album** given the list of track ids of that **specific album** as seen in the JSON data above.

Comment: What's the `id` stands for? the Album or Order?

Comment: as i can understand you want to display this sorted tract ids of a specific album?

Comment: @aircraft `The ids in the JSON data refer to the primary key of the tracks.` I wrote it there in the original post

Comment: 1. Specific Album, 2. I want to update not display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I made a (trivial) change to the payload from the frontend to the endpoint.
2. I use Django Rest Framework but there was nothing special I can reuse from DRF.
3. I use Django bulk update https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update to help with the mass updating (this was actually quite useful)
4. I chose to use patch as the method and not to return any content if successful other than the number of affected rows
5. I  removed the unique_together constraint in the Track model. (this is very important)

#### Change to the payload

Instead of

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12},{"id":13},{"id":75},{"id":76},{"id":77},{"id":78}]
```

I did

```
{"children" :[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12},{"id":13},{"id":75},{"id":76},{"id":77},{"id":78}]}
```

#### the DRF endpoint

in urls.py

```
url(r'^(?i)api/v1.0/album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update_children_order$',
        views.TracksList.as_view(),
        name='view-tracks'),
```

in views.py

```
from django_bulk_update.helper import bulk_update
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json
from rest_framework.views import APIView

 class TracksReorder(APIView):

    def patch(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        Update the order of the tracks by the parent album id
        request.data is in the expected structure:
        track pk is in data.children.{n}.id
        """
        # because the data is expected to be nested dictionary
        decoded = request.body.decode('utf8')
        data = json.loads(decoded)

        sorted_dict = {}
        for key, value in enumerate(data['children']):
            sorted_dict[value['id']] = key

        # sorted dict uses track pk as key and new order as value
        tracks = Track.objects.filter(album_id=pk)
        for track in tracks:
            track.order = sorted_dict[track.id]
        affected_rows = bulk_update(tracks, update_fields=['order'])
        if affected_rows:
            return Response({'affected_rows': affected_rows})
        return Response({}, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would recommend removing that unique constraint, it will make your life *way* more difficult in my opinion.

Seriously, I don't think putting a unique constraint on the ordering is a good idea, remove it, ensure validation for sane values, and cascade your ordering, moving on...

If you want to update the ordering of your tracks you'll need to juggle around the orders, heres some python pseudocode:

```
#  original ordering is {"1":1, "2":2, "3":3}
request_data = {"3":1, "2":3, "1":2}

# I need to get a track to filter on the album
example_track = Track.objects.get(pk=request_data.keys()[0])
the_album = example_track.album

#  Get the largest ordering value, so we can update these to avoid collisions which throw duplicate value errors from the database
tmp_order = max(Track.objects.filter(album=album).values_list('order', flat=True)) + 1

# Reorder all your tracks using the tmp_order, tmp_order is big enough to never collide with other orderings...
for track in Track.objects.filter(pk__in=list(request_data.keys()):
    track.order = tmp_order
    track.save()
    tmp_order = tmp_order + 1

# Update the tracks again to set the final ordering
for track_id, order_num in request_data:
    track = Track.objects.get(pk=track_id)
    track.order = order_num
    track.save()
```

One problem with this solution is that if the request_data does not include all the tracks in the album, it could still hit a collision and error!

```
#  original ordering is {"1":1, "2":2, "3":3, "4": 4}
request_data = {"3":1, "2":3, "1":4}
```

Because Track #4 is not included in the request data and there is no other value to give it for the ordering, Track #1 could never be assigned an ordering of 4 unless your willing to change the ordering of Track #4.

This example is partly why I recommend not enforcing unique ordering on your Tracks.  Instead of enforcing integrity on the database, you could use validation in your application logic, and you will avoid the massive pita that are database integrity constraints in this case.  What happens if two tracks have the same order? They should order by some other field (track name), this isn't a terrible result and doesn't break anything, its equivalent to a use putting two items in the wrong order! This will make it much easier for you to write a maintainable app.

Comment: I agree abt removing the constraint. I think I finally got it to work myself. Thanks for answering by the way. It's still very useful.